# TinyMCE expand JS function to page height like in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

Like wordpress post editor tinymce, I use the same editor in my website and want to implement wordpress editor expand function that expands to fit content as being write, and keeps the formatting tools available at all times.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/js/editor-expand.js

Comment: use fullscreen option inside toolbar

Answer (score 0):

```
**if i understood you right this may be the solutions**    
<script type="text/javascript">

    tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea",
       plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages",
      ],
    relative_urls: false,
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image jbimages | fullscreen |preview | mybutton",

    });
    </script>
```